# Tranpose data and keep first column as a column names and store second column as rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to transpose my data:

```
      title         values
0          Ad ID:        5702319
1       Category:  Cars for Sale
2      Locations:     Phnom Penh
3         Posted:      19-Aug-21
4           View:          12517
500        Ad ID:        7023451
..             ...            ...
566     Condition:           Used
567     Body Type:         Pickup
568          Fuel:         Petrol
569  Transmission:           Auto
570         Price:             $2
```

so that keeps use title as a column name and values as a row. The 'title' column contains unique categories about cars.
so I want data like:

```
 ID.   | Category|  Location|Posted ...    |Transmission|Price|
______________________________________________________________
5702319| Car-sale| PhnomPenh| 22.01.2021...|Auto       |$24000
7023451| Car-sale| PhnomPenh| 21.12.2021...|Manual.    |$7000
```

Comment: Use `pd.crosstab(df['values'], df['title'])`

Answer (score 2):

If `Ad ID:` value always is first per groups for created new row in ouput use [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) for remove last `:` with create groups by compare `Ad ID` with cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and last pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1 = (df.assign(title = df['title'].str.rstrip(':'),
                g = lambda x: x['title'].eq('Ad ID').cumsum())
         .pivot('g','title','values')
         )
print (df1)
title    Ad ID Body Type       Category Condition    Fuel   Locations  \
g                                                                       
1      5702319       NaN  Cars for Sale       NaN     NaN  Phnom Penh   
2      7023451    Pickup            NaN      Used  Petrol         NaN   

title     Posted Price Transmission   View  
g                                           
1      19-Aug-21   NaN          NaN  12517  
2            NaN    $2         Auto    NaN
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I am a freshman on python)), please don't get angry if I ask crazy questions. I have tried your answer but I couldn't get the exact solution. The raw data on the top is a data frame and I need to transpose it so that it will be sorted as I showed. Some categories have no values I need to fill them, NaN. For ex: there is no information about fuel or transmission but it must be filled as NaN. Thanks in advance

Comment: @AllekovPolat - If each row start by `AD ID:` then solution add `NaN`s for not existed valeus like in sample in question. Maybe there is another problem if not working well for you